# How to use jQuery datatable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I'm really new jQuery and MVC3, I downloaded the jquery datatable plugin from http://datatables.net/  and I'm completely confused on how to implement the table. I'm just trying to display the table, I don't care whats on it, I just would like to get it up on the view first. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

In the main view, I don't know exactly what scripts I need or don't need:

```
<h2>About</h2>
@*<script src="../../Scripts/DataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.MetaData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@*<script src="../../Scripts/model.column.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/model.search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/model.row.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/model.ext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
@*<script src="../../Scripts/model.defaults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/model.defaults.columns.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>*@
<link href="../../Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#usersGrid').dataTable({
        aoData: [{}]
    }); 
</script>

<script type="text/jscript">
    $('#usersGrid').dataTable({
        aoData: [{}]
    }); 
</script>

<table id="table_id">   
    <thead>        
        <tr>            
            <th>Column 1</th>         
            <th>Column 2</th>          
            <th>etc</th>       
        </tr>   
    </thead> 
    <tbody>  
        <tr>       
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>   
            <td>etc</td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td> 
            <td>etc</td>  
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Being unfamiliar with DataTables, the only comment I have is that you don't need to include both jquery.dataTables.js and jquery.dataTables.min.js.  The ".min" denotes that it is a "minified" version (the same script compacted into a less readable but smaller file, to save bandwidth).  So you can pick one or the other.

Comment: oh well thx thats something i didn't know. There really isn't any good tutorials anywhere where someone actually shows step by step how to use these jquery plugins

Comment: start with just the scripts and css from examples and work from there

Comment: https://www.bmthrive.com/datatables-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've always felt that the DataTables website had pretty good examples, all with sample code. There aren't step-by-step directions, necessarily, but the more basic examples are pretty straightforward.

Regardless, in its simplest form, all you need to get DataTables working is a valid jQuery object (and the DataTables source, of course). One problem in your code above is that your table has an ID of `table_id`, yet you're trying to initialize dataTables on a table with an ID of `usersGrid`. Also, you should put the initialization code within `$(document).ready()`

I put together [this quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EFk9H/) for you to look at. It doesn't have all the fancy buttons and things, but the basic functionality is all there - you can sort columns, etc. Notice how the ID of the table corresponds to the jQuery selector. Other than that, all you have to do is call the `.dataTable()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_id').dataTable();
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Simple Following two script for jquery DataTable

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Use Css For add style of tabel

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
```

Run jquery function for display datatable

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    $(document).ready(function() {$('#TABLE_ID').dataTable({'iDisplayLength': 2,//Set Row Per Page
    "bFilter": false,//Remove Search
    "bPaginate" : false,//Remove Pagination
    "bInfo": false,//Remove Page Info
    "bLengthChange":false,//Show per Page Dropdown Remove
    "columnDefs": [ { "targets": 0, "orderable": false } ],//Remove Colum Orderable(Here Col 0 Remove)
    "aoColumns": [{ "asSorting": [] },{ "asSorting": [ "asc" ] },{ "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ] },{ "asSorting": [ "desc" ] },null],//Set Colum Order By ASC Or DSC
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"//Full Pagination
    });
    });
</script>
```

Create Table For apply jquery datatable.

```
<table id="TABLE_ID"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th></tr></thead><tfoot><tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th></tr></tfoot><tbody><tr><td>Tiger Nixon</td><td>System Architect</td></tr><tr><td>Garrett Winters</td><td>Accountant</td></tr><tr><td>Ashton Cox</td><td>Junior Technical Author</td></tr><tr><td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Senior Javascript Developer</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Here create Table must User `<thead>` and `<tbody>`Tag for apply jQuery in Table.

Answer (score 0):

The following example may fulfill your requirements which shows the relevant js and css files. In this I am also using jQuery theme for which the third css file is used. You can download first two css files from [datatables](http://datatables.net/) and the third one from jQuery official web site itself.

```
<head>
<link href="../css/table_sort_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/table_sort_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/themes/cupertino/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="../css/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table_id").dataTable({
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "aoColumns": [{ "bSortable": true }, { "bSortable": true }]
    });      
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="table_id">   
<thead>        
    <tr>            
        <th>Column 1</th>         
        <th>Column 2</th>          
        <th>etc</th>       
    </tr>   
</thead> 
<tbody>  
    <tr>       
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>   
        <td>etc</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td> 
        <td>etc</td>  
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using jquery datatable server side.

```
$('#sample-data-table').DataTable({   
    "destroy": true,   
    "processing": false,   
    "serverSide": true,   
    "searching": true,   
    "oLanguage": {   
        "sEmptyTable": "No client available."    
    },    
    "lengthMenu": [    
        [10, 20, 50, -1],    
        [10, 20, 50, "All"]   
    ],   
    "order": [],   
})
```

it will sort the list as i am getting from server-side by OrderByDescending.
but when i add new record and initialize the datatable again, then the last inserted record is not coming on top in the list.